# How to calculate box position when zoomed in on an area

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a `JPanel` which is 995 x 745 pixels large. The panel itself cannot be resized.

The panel contains an image that is 6296 x 7888 pixels large. I didn't create the image and there's no real way to make it smaller without a large amount of quality loss.

Within the image, I've added a bunch (about 230) different "hitboxes", basically just coordinates of where you can click for an event to trigger.

The problem is, when I attempt to zoom in or out of the picture, those hitboxes are no longer in the correct position.

I attempted to write multiple different math 'formulas' that would solve this issue however, it only worked for the boxes closest to the top left corner.

The further right it got the more and more the boxes were shifted to the left. Either that, or one zoom tick would make the boxes move 400 pixels away.

I've only started working on the X portion right now because it's more complicated to try and solve both at once.

This is the code I have:

```
if ((clickX >= getLocationX(l.getClickX()) && clickX <= (getLocationX(l.getClickX()) + getBoxSize()))
        && (clickY >= getLocationY(l.getClickY())
        && clickY <= (getLocationY(l.getClickY()) + getBoxSize()))) {
    System.out.println("Clicked box");
}
```

And the methods:

```
private int getLocationX(int initialX) {
    if (zoomMod < 0) {
        // Zoom out.
        return (int) (((initialX - 85) + currentX) + ((int) (zoomMod * 0.006)));// 0.0004
    } else {
        // Zoom in.
        return (int) (((initialX - 85) + currentX) + ((int) (zoomMod * 0.0004)));// 0.0004
    }
}

private int getLocationY(int initialY) {
    return ((initialY - 85) + currentY);
}

private int getBoxSize() {
    if (zoomMod < 0) {
        return 170 - ((int) Math.abs(zoomMod * 0.0173));
    } else {
        return ((int) (zoomMod * .028)) + 170;
    }
}
```

This is what it'd look like without zoom:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTvMr.png)

And when zoomed in fully:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW4MO.png)